# How to navigate a page by using prev and next button like slide show for set of 10 ques?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, slideshow

I'm creating an online tutorial app. In that i want to conduct online test by using set of 10 questions.Could  you suggest me in what way i have to design using  previous and next button.My condition is,there should be a single Viewcontroller with multiple views(10),the view should change according to prev and next button in the tab bar. 
  Thanks for consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @poojathorat, @Nilesh, @Akshay said you don't need so many viewcontrollers or even that many views. Just have a label and a couple of buttons and have your questions in an array. When the button is clicked change the label text accordingly.

To give you a head start,

```
// global variables
let qArray = ["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3", "Question 4", "Question 5"]
var currIndex = 0
var qLbl: UILabel!
```

This method will add respective label and buttons

```
func addQuestionView() {
    let qView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    qView.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()

    qLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: qView.frame.size.width, height: qView.frame.size.height/2))
    qLbl.text = qArray[currIndex]
    qLbl.textAlignment = .Center

    let prevBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: qView.frame.size.height-50, width: qView.frame.size.width/2, height: 50))
    prevBtn.tag = 15
    prevBtn.setTitle("Prev", forState: .Normal)
    prevBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    prevBtn.addTarget(self, action: "prevBtnAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    let nextBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: qView.frame.size.width/2, y: qView.frame.size.height-50, width: qView.frame.size.width/2, height: 50))
    nextBtn.tag = 16
    nextBtn.setTitle("Next", forState: .Normal)
    nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    nextBtn.addTarget(self, action: "nextBtnAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    qView.addSubview(qLbl)
    qView.addSubview(prevBtn)
    qView.addSubview(nextBtn)

    self.view.addSubview(qView)
}
```

And the buttons actions

```
func prevBtnAction() {
    currIndex--
    if currIndex >= 0 {
        qLbl.text = qArray[currIndex]
    } else {
        currIndex++
    }
}

func nextBtnAction() {
    currIndex++
    if currIndex < qArray.count {
        qLbl.text = qArray[currIndex]
    } else {
        currIndex--
    }
}
```

You can simplify even further but this is just for understanding. Hope it helps.

Comment: How can i display answer options here?

Comment: Yes exactly using radio button.

Comment: radio buttons are not built-in objects in xcode, but its pretty simple to replicate radio buttons using UIButtons. Get two images representing selected button and an unselected button and in the button action change the button imageView.image alternatively

Answer (score 2):

You have to take all the 10 questions in 1 array & on click of prev next button change the index of array & show the contents in view which contain textview.There is no need of 10 views/Maintain only one view & change contents.Like on Next button increase the counter

```
 i++;
 NSString *new = [questionSequenceArray objectAtIndex:i] 
 questionText.text=new;
```

Comment: Thank u very much.I'm very new to iOS.Could u please suggest me using swift?

Answer (score 0):

It depeds on your requirement, if each page contains single question and options no need of creating 10 different viecontrollers and you can use views efficiently,

If all questions are identical  like just question and options you can use single reusable view. Unless you have each question will have different type of answers such as emojis, photo selection, etc.,
Better use reusable single view, move with animations and load appropriate data from objects. After completing all questions you can navigate to conclusion viewcontroller. My suggestion is not to create 10 unusable viewcontollers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way,

- Create one single view & array of your question then manage it using the previous/next button event in one controller. If you would like to display it with animation the need to some work on that.
- You can even try to push the same controller every time with updated array index.